# When will you no longer be able to update windows 7 to windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

Is there a date that the free upgrade to windows 10 is no longer offered for windows 7 and windows 8 users? If so what is the date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have until July 29, 2016 to take advantage of this free upgrade offer. Once you upgrade, you’ll have Windows 10 for free on that device.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-faq